# Print Excel file as multiple PDF

Tags: print-to-pdf

I have multiple data in Excel which by inserting page breaks as multiple pages (20 pages) which are properly appearing.

I want to print to PDF as 20 `.pdf` files to be created, so that I can send related sheet to related persons. (Basically these are pay slips)

Kindly advice how to do?

[image: print page]

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 :

You may print all as pdf, then use a pdf splitter. Offline (Eg https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/foxit-phantompdf/9nd1jwbgzmqf#activetab=pivot:overviewtab or https://www.foxit.com/pdf-editor/ ) or online (Eg https://smallpdf.com/ ) should do.

### Option 2a :

Enter the page number @ **Pages:**
[image: page]

### Option 2b :

Same as above.. but using a browser. Open the file in browser to make it work (I'm using firefox)

[image: print]